# I want to change the height of an element twice using one jquery animation but I can't. How to do it?

Tags: jquery, animation

I want to change the height of an element twice using one jquery animation but I can't. How to do it?

I am using the code:

```
$("#animate").click(function() {
$("#content")
    .animate({"height": "200px"},{"queue": true, "duration": 500})
    .animate({"width": "250px"}, {"queue": true, "duration": 500});
    .animate({"height": "100px"},{"queue": true, "duration": 500})
});
```

And nothing is happenning..
But if I remove any one of the height animation it works fine.
Thanks in advance..

Comment: can have a look at <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11065626/jquery-dynamically-change-element-height>

Comment: try thisL: $("#content")
    .animate({"height": "200px"},{"queue": true, "duration": 500})
    .animate({"width": "250px"}, {"queue": true, "duration": 500})
    .animate({"height": "100px"},{"queue": true, "duration": 500})
});

Comment: after the width animate statement you close it using ';' jQuery does not know to which element it should apply the third animate statement. Eitherremove the ';' or specify the element for the third animate statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a syntax error in your code as well as you may have to postpone the second height animation till the first one is completed

```
$("#animate").click(function() {
$("#content").animate({
            "height" : "200px"
        }, {
            "queue" : true,
            "duration" : 500,
            complete : function() {
                $(this).animate({
                            "height" : "100px"
                        }, {
                            "queue" : true,
                            "duration" : 500
                        })
            }
        }).animate({
            "width" : "250px"
        }, {
            "queue" : true,
            "duration" : 500
        });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to remove the `;`:

```
.animate({"width": "250px"}, {"queue": true, "duration": 500}); // <-- Here
```

Answer (score 1):

make it in a chain:

```
$("#content").animate({"height": 200}, 500, function(){
   $(this).animate({"width" : 250}, 500, function(){
      $(this).animate({"height" : 100}, 500)
   })
});
```